# Webdriverio: Latest chrome browser version (65.0.3325.162) is not supporting webdriverio

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver-io

Latest chrome browser version (65.0.3325.162) is not supporting webdriverio

Browser is getting launched and also hits the url successfully.

but while performing operation on UI is throwing different error.

Here are some error I have got:

Case 1: Typing in a Text box
Method Used:  setValue()

unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
[chrome #0-0] Error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
[chrome #0-0]     at elementIdValue("0", "text123")

Case 2: Selecting a value from drop down
Method used: selectByVisibleText()

stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
[chrome #0-0] Error: An element command failed because the referenced element is no longer attached to the DOM.
[chrome #0-0]     at elementIdClick("1")

Note: Same code was working fine with the previous version of Chrome browser (64.0.3282.186)
Since there is no way we can downgrade chrome version we have to go for the latest chrome browser only.

Since it works well in Firefox and Chrome previous version I don't think it is a problem with webdriverIO.

Just let me know is there anybody else have faced the same problem or if anybody can reproduce this issues and give some solution to the problem stated.

Answer (score 1):

I just found exactly the same problem. I was about to post about it when your post came up. I tried the following code. Whilst it works with firefox it fails with chrome throwing the error you mention.

```
  browser.url('http://www.google.com')
  .element('[name="q"]')
  .setValue('webdriver')
  .element('[name="btnK"]')
  .click()
```

EDIT: In this issue https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/2631 they mention that upgrading the chromedriver to the version 2.36.0 it fixes the issue.

It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading "wdio-selenium-standalone-service" from 0.0.9 to 0.0.10 fixed it for me.